# Theorem 9.34 Rudin

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, linear-transformations, determinant

[image]

[image]

I don't understand what do we mean in $j_q$ and $j_p$.
I also don't understand part $(b)$ of 9.34 theorem.
I could n't understand this sentence: "det is a linear function of each of the column vectors $x_j$, if the others are held fixed" and there by from Where did $n!$ come?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: In the product of equation (82), we are iterating over all pairs of indices $(p,q) \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$ such that $p < q$. Therefore $j_p$ and $j_q$ are a pair of elements from the set $\{j_1, \dotsc, j_n\}$ such that $p < q$, in other words, $j_p$ precedes $j_q$ in the ordered $n$-uple $(j_1, \dotsc, j_n)$.
For example we take the couples $(j_1, j_2)$ and $(j_2, j_4)$, but not the couples $(j_2, j_1)$, $(j_1, j_1)$ or $(j_4, j_2)$.

For the second part: $\det$ is a linear map of each of the column vectors $x_j$ means that
$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & \dots & (\lambda x_j + y_j) & \dots & x_n 
\end{pmatrix} 
= \\
\lambda \det\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & \dots & x_j & \dots & x_n 
\end{pmatrix} 
+
\det\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & \dots & y_j & \dots & x_n 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
for every scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, for every column vectors $x_j, y_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and for any index $j \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$.

The $n!$ comes from the fact that we are iterating over all the $n$-tuples $(j_1, \dotsc, j_n)$ with $1 \leq j_r \leq n$, for every $r \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$, i.e. over all the permutations of the $n$-elements set $\{j_1, \dotsc, j_n\}$. A basic combinatorial argument gives $n!$ as the number of permutations of such set.

Comment: are $j_1,j_2,....j_n$ natural numbers?

Comment: In definition 9.33 they are integers. Then, when they are used to define the determinant they are also supposed to be between $1$ and $r$, so yes, they are natural numbers (indices of the rows/columns of a matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Proof

If $A= I$, then $a(i,i)=1$ and $a(i,j)=0$ for $i≠j$. Hence
$$det [I]=∑ s(j_1,...,j_n )\;  a(1,j_1 )\;  a(2,j_2 )\;\dots\; a(n,j_n)= s(1,2,...,n)= 1, $$
which proves (a).

By

(82)$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;s(j_1,...,j_n )=∏_{p<q}\; sgn (j_q-j_p ),$

$$s(j_1,...,j_n )=0 \text{ if any two of the j's are equal.} $$
Each of the remaining  $n!$ products in

(83) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; det [A]=∑ s(j_1,...,j_n )  a(1,j_1 )  a(2,j_2 )… a(n,j_n) $

contains exactly one factor from each column(*hence det treats each column linearly if others are held fixed*). This proves (b).

Part (c) is an immediate consequence of the fact that $ s(j_1,...,j_n )$, changes sign if any two of the $j's$ are interchanged, and (d) is a corollary of (c).

Note: To understand (b), Let $ x_j   (j=1,…,n)$ and $y_j $ be column vectors.

Then,
$$det⁡(x_1,…,x_{j-1},x_j+y_j,x_{j+1},…,x_n )=det⁡(x_1,…,x_{j-1},x_j,x_{j+1},…,x_n )
+det⁡(x_1,…,x_{j-1},y_j,x_{j+1},…,x_n )   $$
and
$$det⁡(x_1,…,x_{j-1},cx_j,x_{j+1},…,x_n )=c\; det⁡(x_1,…,x_{j-1},x_j,x_{j+1},…,x_n ) $$
for any scalar $c$.

Hence *det is a linear function of each of the column vectors $x_j$, if the others are held fixed*.

For (d), if $[A]$ has two equal columns say $x_i=x_j $, then interchanging the ith and jth columns doesn’t affect $[A]$, that is,  $[A]_1=[A]$. Then it follows that
det $[A]_1=det [A]$.

But by (c),  $det [A]_1=-det [A]$. Hence we get $det [A]=0.$

Comment: How does in (b) having one factor from each column imply linearity exactly?